# Failed installation ASP4::ModPerl & ASP4x::Router perl modules

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the ASP4::ModPerl and ASP4x::Router Perl modules using cpanminus but the installation failed with error "! Bailing out the installation for ASP4-1.087". Looks like some dependencies failed. But when I try to install that failed dependencies they fail with the same error.
`--force` flag didn't help

OS: ubuntu:12.04 
Perl version (v5.14.2)

Here its output

```
root@153b5b0c1c09:/# cpanm ASP4::ModPerl
--> Working on ASP4::ModPerl
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JO/JOHND/ASP4-1.087.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ASP4-1.087 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::Memory::Cycle, JSON::XS, Ima::DBI::Contextual, Term::ReadKey, DBI, HTML::Form, HTTP::Body, HTTP::Date, Data::Properties::JSON, Mail::Sendmail, common::sense, Data::Properties::YAML
--> Working on Test::Memory::Cycle
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PE/PETDANCE/Test-Memory-Cycle-1.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Memory-Cycle-1.06 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: PadWalker, Devel::Cycle
--> Working on PadWalker
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/R/RO/ROBIN/PadWalker-2.2.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring PadWalker-2.2 ... OK
Building and testing PadWalker-2.2 ... FAIL
! Installing PadWalker failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
--> Working on Devel::Cycle
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/Devel-Cycle-1.12.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Devel-Cycle-1.12 ... OK
Building and testing Devel-Cycle-1.12 ... OK
Successfully installed Devel-Cycle-1.12
! Bailing out the installation for Test-Memory-Cycle-1.06. Retry with --prompt or --force.
--> Working on JSON::XS
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/JSON-XS-3.04.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Canary::Stability
--> Working on Canary::Stability
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Canary-Stability-2012.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Canary-Stability-2012 ... OK
Building and testing Canary-Stability-2012 ... OK
Successfully installed Canary-Stability-2012
Configuring JSON-XS-3.04 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Types::Serialiser, common::sense
--> Working on Types::Serialiser
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Types-Serialiser-1.0.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Types-Serialiser-1.0 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: common::sense
--> Working on common::sense
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/common-sense-3.74.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring common-sense-3.74 ... OK
Building and testing common-sense-3.74 ... OK
Successfully installed common-sense-3.74
Building and testing Types-Serialiser-1.0 ... OK
Successfully installed Types-Serialiser-1.0
Building and testing JSON-XS-3.04 ... FAIL
! Installing JSON::XS failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
--> Working on Ima::DBI::Contextual
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JO/JOHND/Ima-DBI-Contextual-1.006.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Ima::DBI::Contextual-1.006 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: DBD::SQLite, DBI
--> Working on DBD::SQLite
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IS/ISHIGAKI/DBD-SQLite-1.54.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: DBI
--> Working on DBI
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.637.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DBI-1.637 ... OK
Building and testing DBI-1.637 ... FAIL
! Installing DBI failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
! Bailing out the installation for DBD-SQLite-1.54. Retry with --prompt or --force.
! Bailing out the installation for Ima-DBI-Contextual-1.006. Retry with --prompt or --force.
--> Working on Term::ReadKey
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JS/JSTOWE/TermReadKey-2.37.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: ExtUtils::MakeMaker
--> Working on ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30 ... OK
Building and testing ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30 ... OK
Successfully installed ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30 (upgraded from 6.57_05)
Configuring TermReadKey-2.37 ... OK
Building and testing TermReadKey-2.37 ... FAIL
! Installing Term::ReadKey failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
--> Working on HTML::Form
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Form-6.03.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTML-Form-6.03 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: URI, HTML::TokeParser, HTTP::Request, HTTP::Request::Common
--> Working on URI
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.72.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring URI-1.72 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::Needs
--> Working on Test::Needs
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/Test-Needs-0.002005.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Needs-0.002005 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Needs-0.002005 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Needs-0.002005
Building and testing URI-1.72 ... OK
Successfully installed URI-1.72
--> Working on HTML::TokeParser
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTML-Parser-3.72 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: HTML::Tagset
--> Working on HTML::Tagset
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PE/PETDANCE/HTML-Tagset-3.20.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTML-Tagset-3.20 ... OK
Building and testing HTML-Tagset-3.20 ... OK
Successfully installed HTML-Tagset-3.20
Building and testing HTML-Parser-3.72 ... FAIL
! Installing HTML::TokeParser failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
--> Working on HTTP::Request
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/O/OA/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.13.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTTP-Message-6.13 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: LWP::MediaTypes, Encode::Locale, IO::HTML, HTTP::Date
--> Working on LWP::MediaTypes
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/LWP-MediaTypes-6.02.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring LWP-MediaTypes-6.02 ... OK
Building and testing LWP-MediaTypes-6.02 ... OK
Successfully installed LWP-MediaTypes-6.02
--> Working on Encode::Locale
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.05.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Encode-Locale-1.05 ... OK
Building and testing Encode-Locale-1.05 ... OK
Successfully installed Encode-Locale-1.05
--> Working on IO::HTML
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CJ/CJM/IO-HTML-1.001.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring IO-HTML-1.001 ... OK
Building and testing IO-HTML-1.001 ... OK
Successfully installed IO-HTML-1.001
--> Working on HTTP::Date
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTTP-Date-6.02.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTTP-Date-6.02 ... OK
Building and testing HTTP-Date-6.02 ... OK
Successfully installed HTTP-Date-6.02
Building and testing HTTP-Message-6.13 ... OK
Successfully installed HTTP-Message-6.13
! Bailing out the installation for HTML-Form-6.03. Retry with --prompt or --force.
--> Working on HTTP::Body
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GE/GETTY/HTTP-Body-1.22.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring HTTP-Body-1.22 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::Deep
--> Working on Test::Deep
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Test-Deep-1.127.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Deep-1.127 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::Tester
--> Working on Test::Tester
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/E/EX/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302096.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Simple-1.302096 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Simple-1.302096 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Simple-1.302096
Package 'Test2::Util::HashBase' already declared with version '0.005',
ignoring subsequent declaration on line 18.
Building and testing Test-Deep-1.127 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Deep-1.127
Building and testing HTTP-Body-1.22 ... OK
Successfully installed HTTP-Body-1.22
--> Working on Data::Properties::JSON
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JO/JOHND/Data-Properties-JSON-0.004.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Data-Properties-JSON-0.004 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: JSON::XS
Building and testing Data-Properties-JSON-0.004 ... FAIL
! Installing Data::Properties::JSON failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
--> Working on Mail::Sendmail
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/N/NE/NEILB/Mail-Sendmail-0.80.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Mail-Sendmail-0.80 ... OK
Building and testing Mail-Sendmail-0.80 ... OK
Successfully installed Mail-Sendmail-0.80
--> Working on Data::Properties::YAML
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JO/JOHND/Data-Properties-YAML-0.04.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Data-Properties-YAML-0.04 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: YAML
--> Working on YAML
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/YAML-1.23.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring YAML-1.23 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::YAML
--> Working on Test::YAML
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/Test-YAML-1.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-YAML-1.06 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::Base
--> Working on Test::Base
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/Test-Base-0.88.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Base-0.88 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Text::Diff, Algorithm::Diff, Spiffy
--> Working on Text::Diff
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/N/NE/NEILB/Text-Diff-1.45.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Text-Diff-1.45 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Algorithm::Diff
--> Working on Algorithm::Diff
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/T/TY/TYEMQ/Algorithm-Diff-1.1903.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Algorithm-Diff-1.1903 ... OK
Building and testing Algorithm-Diff-1.1903 ... OK
Successfully installed Algorithm-Diff-1.1903
Building and testing Text-Diff-1.45 ... OK
Successfully installed Text-Diff-1.45
--> Working on Spiffy
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/Spiffy-0.46.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Spiffy-0.46 ... OK
Building and testing Spiffy-0.46 ... OK
Successfully installed Spiffy-0.46
Building and testing Test-Base-0.88 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Base-0.88
Building and testing Test-YAML-1.06 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-YAML-1.06
Building and testing YAML-1.23 ... OK
Successfully installed YAML-1.23
Building and testing Data-Properties-YAML-0.04 ... OK
Successfully installed Data-Properties-YAML-0.04
! Bailing out the installation for ASP4-1.087. Retry with --prompt or --force.
24 distributions installed
```

and only error messages from /root/.cpanm/build.log

```
-> FAIL Installing JSON::XS failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Installing DBI failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for DBD-SQLite-1.54. Retry with --prompt or --force.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Ima::DBI::Contextual-1.006. Retry with --prompt or --force.
-> FAIL Installing Term::ReadKey failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Installing HTML::TokeParser failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for HTML-Form-6.03. Retry with --prompt or --force.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for ASP4-1.087. Retry with --prompt or --force.
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message. It looks like you forgot a word.

Comment: Did you read _/root/.cpanm/build.log_ to see what the problem is? From the modules that failed, I'm guessing you are probably missing a system package with libxml2 or something similar for the HTML parser.

Comment: Yes, but in /root/.cpanm/build.log  I didn't find anything useful. There are error messages about failing dependencies like `FAIL Bailing out the installation for DBD-SQLite-1.54. Retry with --prompt or --force.` and I couldn't install them as well `Building and testing DBI-1.637 ... FAIL
! Installing DBI failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
! Bailing out the installation for DBD-SQLite-1.54. Retry with --prompt or --force.`

Comment: Try installing just one of those, and look at the logs.

Comment: Thank you! investigation of logs of one the dependency modules helped me to discover that there was missing cc compiler. The issue is resolved now.